# Recursive search for folder in directory

Tags: cmd

There is simple [command](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) for finding file (not folder) in given directory, which works something like this:

`where /r GroupManagementAppServer test.js`
returns all files named `test.js` in the folder `GroupManagementAppServer`.

However, this command fails for two other use cases:

1. User specifies, as last argument, a pathname relative to some directory (like, in the first example, `var/www/html/project/js/test.js`, which is somewhere in `GroupManagementAppServer`)
2. User specifies, as last argument, a folder (like, in the first example, `js`)

I need some command-line logic to handle all those use cases, so that I can finish implementing my logic to verify two parameters, so that I can finish writing my routine that will serve as the "business-end" of my code. (I'm working on a command-line script that generates markdown files for code files in my project. I've been stuck on this task for days and it is time to move on and get some real work done.)

Comment: What does it mean if the user specifies a directory to recurse from *and* a relative pathname? Does the root of the relative pathname have to be a subdirectory of the first argument? Or does the presence of a relative pathname mean "do not recurse"? Or something else?

Comment: For example, if I wanted to look in `GroupManagementAppServer` for a file that had path `var/www/html/project/js/test.js` relative to some directory in `GroupManagementAppServer`, I should be able to do that and get its path.

Comment: I added some more words for clarity in the question.

Comment: `where /r` doesn't work with folders. `dir /s /b` does, but unfortunately doesn't work with relative pathnames. One way around this restriction is to parse the first folder of the pathname, do a `dir /s /b` for just that folder, `cd` (or `pushd`) into it, then check if the rest of the pathname exists. Cumbersome, but possible, if no-one comes up with a better solution.

Comment: What about `dir /B /S /A:-D "GroupManagementAppServer\test.js" | findstr /I /E /C:"\var\www\html\project\js\test.js"`, so `dir` returns all files `test.js` found in the root directory `GroupManagementAppServer` recursively with the list filtered by `findstr` to match the relative path (you have to use the `\ `as path separator then; note also the leading `\ `)? To do the same for folders, change `/A:-D` to `/A:D`.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` command can only search for files but not for directories; use `dir` instead, which can search for both files (using the option `/A:-D`) and for directories (using the option `/A:D`).

#### Use Case 1

`dir /S` can be used to recursively search for items that match a given name or pattern, but it cannot be used to search for items whose relative paths match a given one. However, you can use `findstr` to filter the output of `dir /S`, like this:

```dos
rem // Define constants here:
set "RootDir=GroupManagementAppServer"
set "RelPath=var\www\html\project\js\test.js"

rem /* Let `dir` return all files in full tree, then let `findstr` filter for matches;
rem    each `\` needs to be doubled as `\` is used as escape character by `findstr`: */
dir /B /S /A:-D "%RootDir%\*" | findstr /I /E /C:"\\%RelPath:\=\\%"
```

#### Use Case 2

Actually I am not quite sure what you mean, but I guess you want the user to be able to just input the name or the relative path of the immediate parent directory (like `js`) of the file `test.js`. I do not know how you want to distinguish between files and directories, unless we can assume that directory names do not hold an extension.

Supposing my assumptions are right, and the user input does not contain any wild-cards (`?`, `*`), you can use a `for` loop to determine whether or not there is an extension:

```dos
rem // Let us assume variable `RelPath` holds the user input:
for %%I in ("%RelPath%") do set "EXT=%%~xI"
rem // Check whether the extension is missing:
if not defined EXT (
    rem /* There is no extension, so let us assume the user input is a directory;
    rem    so let us append the default file name `test.js` in that case: */
    set "RelPath=%RelPath%\test.js"
)
rem // Continue with the `dir`/`findstr` approach from use case 1 here...
```